# jQuery on change/input not working when updating value via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-on

I have noticed that the event for `$('#firstId')` is not firing when the change is done by the Javascript itself.

Why is this the case?

Is there a way to still fire the event?

**Here is an example:**

```js
$('#firstId').on('change input paste', function(){
  console.log("this is the input event being fired");
});

$('#randomButton').on('click', function(){
  $('#firstId').val(Math.floor(Math.random()*2147483647 )+1);
  console.log("randomButton being fired");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span for="firstId">number: </span>
<input type="number" id="firstId"/>
<p>Or</p>
<button id="randomButton">Get a random number</button><br>
```

Comment: I am sorry, what is not working?

Comment: You will have to manually fire necessary function after its updated from JS

Comment: @AniketSahrawat He means if I do `$("#firstId").val('test')` no event is fired

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is because all the events attached above via handler are triggered by user action and not via code. you can use `.trigger()` or `.change()` here to trigger the event:

```
$('#firstId').val(Math.floor(Math.random()*2147483647 )+1).change();
```

or

```
$('#firstId').val(Math.floor(Math.random()*2147483647 )+1).trigger('change');
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks for reminding me about the fact that event have to be triggered by user input

Comment: @KevinKloet: glad it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, really helped! For anyone using the better approach for input listening `.on("input")`, remember to do `.trigger("input")`  instead :)